# Jquery add class to non empty inputs and textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m looking for a solution,to non empty inputs and textareas add aditional class.

I have a solution, which work perfect for textares, but not for inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="move" value="something"> 

<textarea type="text" class="move">something</textarea>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.move:not(:empty)').addClass('used');

});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the class "used"? Not sure what you want to display in your boxes, All of them have "something" displayed at the moment

Comment: the class used is added after reaload of the page - this is only example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with CSS pseudo selectors, look what happen:

```js
$(function() {

    $('.move:empty').addClass('used');

});
```

```css
.used {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="move" value="something">
<input type="text" class="move" value="">
<textarea type="text" class="move">something</textarea>
```

retrieving input's value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.move').each(function(e,i){
      if(this.value !== "") $(this).addClass('used');
    });

});
```

```css
.used {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" class="move">something</textarea>
<input type="text" class="move" value="something">
<input type="text" class="move" value="">
```